# How to push the data from database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to push the data from database to application instead of application pull the data.I have installed ms sql server and apache tomcat server. I have my application in apache tomcat, here I made connection to database. Now I want database send the data whenever there is update in data. But all I know is fetch the data from database is not good idea, because application needs to monitor the database for updated data will lead to fire the query for every 5 sec, this is not efficient as well.

I read some tutorials in Google for this, Finally I found one method name as `Query Notification` is useful as per requirements.But I don't know how to implement.

1. Tell me, `query Notification` is it good way for me.
2. where will I get good examples.

Comment: You'll have to consult the client stack documentation to see if there's something built in already. If this was .NET land, there are classes built in that leverage the query notification system, and I could give you an answer. An alternative is to still poll periodically, but poll a cache table (or implement change tracking) instead of polling the data directly.

Comment: Look at [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).